# Repeat Table header on all pages of report in word using microsoft.office.interop.word and c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, repeat

I am having a word template with the table header and also the footer. This is copied to target file.  **I need to replicate the header line on all pages**.
the table looks like this

| **Sr.No** |  **TXN. Date**|  **Particulars**        | **Amount**  |

The data append is working fine using Interop.word and c#.

However I need to replicate the **table header** on all pages of the report (**table spread**).

In case of existing links, please guide me.

Comment: Note the distinction in Word between a Table header, which repeats on new pages in the same table and a running head or header which appears on all pages. Please distinguish between these in your question. I am unsure what you mean by footer line in relation to a table.

Comment: The table header needs to be replicated using Interop.word in c#.   The output is a word document containing the table that may have around 30-80 rows depending on the data.